# Are PS3 games exactly the same between PAL and NTSC?

Tags: ps3

I know that PS3 games are region free. I'm not sure whether there is any sort of quality difference if you play PAL games on an NTSC PS3 or vice versa.

Does anyone know?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, there are some minor differences:

- If you are playing on a CRT, a PAL game will output a resolution of 576i, while an NTSC game will output 480i. On my PAL television (which does support NTSC) the difference is very noticable - NTSC looks a lot worse.
- While the games themselves are region-free, sometimes the DLC is not. One example of this is Dragon Age: A friend of mine has the US version, but he has not been able to use any of the DLC from the Australian store - it simply doesn't work.

Answer (score 4):

The concept of NTCS and PAL is meaningless in new consoles. All support all modes of output and NTSC/PAL is only regional protection simillar to the DVD one. Even more: there's no such thing as PAL/NTSC signal over digital (HDMI) or component outputs.

PS3 does not have regional protection, so there is no difference between PAL or NTSC games.

Comment: and that is one of the so many reason to love the ps3

Answer (score 0):

There shouldn't be any difference, but you have to make sure your TV can handle both PAL and NTSC.