# Can I play PS3 games from another country?

Tags: ps3, region-lock, assassins-creed-3

I'm going to buy Assassins Creed 3 on amazon.com, but my friend told me if I buy it from there, I can't play because I have a PS3 from Iceland (where I live).  It is true?

Does the PS3 have region locking that will prevent a US copy of Assassin's Creed 3 from playing on an Icelandic PS3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know all PS3 games are infact region free. The same cannot be said about Blu-Ray movies though.

**[Source 1](http://www.avforums.com/forums/ps3-games/483566-all-ps3-games-region-free.html)**

**[Source 2](http://uk.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20100415125941AAwemro)**

**[Source 3](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Are-games-region-free-PS3/forum/Fx2AIGD9UV24X47/Tx2R9HQZDI3CRVI/1?_encoding=UTF8&asin=B002L16JXS)**

and of course there's **[this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/10865/are-ps3-games-exactly-the-same-between-pal-and-ntsc)** question as pointed out by Colin.

However most of these are only forum posts. If I get chance will have a good search for some concrete evidence from Sony.

Happy gaming :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes. the games are region free.

Check out this question for more information:
[Are PS3 games exactly the same between PAL and NTSC?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/10865/are-ps3-games-exactly-the-same-between-pal-and-ntsc)

notably the: tv and dlc portions.